# How can I pass value between NavigationController and ViewController with StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem,
The following is my StoryBoard,
the first Controller is a `TabBarController`,
and it relation with A (ViewController).

[image: How can I pass value between NavigationController and ViewController with StoryBoard?]

A is a `ViewController`,
B is a `NavigationController`, A change page to B by `modal` segue
C is a `ViewController`, C will change to another page by `push` so I need a NavigationController

OK, I want to pass value from A to C,
now I can pass value from A to B by `prepareForSegue`,
However, because B and C have relationship but not segue,
So I can't pass value from B to C by `prepareForSegue`!!!

How can I pass value between NavigationController and ViewController with StoryBoard?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Storyboard image is a little misleading here.

When you segue to B, *actually* you are segueing to the B/C combo as NavControllers always have at least one viewController in their stack (which is their `topViewController` and their `[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]`).

So you do have a relationship directly from A to C.

How you access that controller depends on whether your segue is *modal* or *push*. In your case it is modal, but I will describe both so you can see the difference.

In either case, to pass data to C, you need to declare a property in it's header file

```
    @interface CviewController: UIViewContrller
    @property (assign) int dataFromA;
    @end
```

**push segue**

In a push segue, it is actually C that is the destinationViewController, not B. In fact the push segue is governed by B, which is the UINavigationController for both A and C. The code behind the push segue is of the form
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewController];`

In AviewController's prepareForSegue:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
        {
         CviewController* controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        [controller setDataFromA:self.data];
    }
```

It is *possible* in the storyboard to make a push segue line between two viewControllers that do *not* share a common UINavigationController. However when you run this you will get a crash error:

> 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'pushC'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Behind every good push segue lies a Navigation Controller.

**modal segue**

The code hiding behind a modal Segue is the UIViewController method
`- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent`

In a modal segue to a NavController/ViewController combo, the destination viewController is whatever the segue line points to. If it points to a viewController, that is the segue.destinationController (and the UINavigationController will be ignored, which is not what you want here); if it points to a UINavigationController, as in this case, *that* will be it's destinationController. But it is still straightforward to access the viewController, as it will be the navigation Controller's topViewController.

In  AviewController's prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     CviewController* controller = 
        (CviewController*)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
    [controller setDataFromA:self.data];
}
```

Note that in this case we have to use old-style [[message passing] syntax]. If we use modern.property.syntax we get a compile error. That's because the program does not know the type of desinationViewController, and refuses to accept topViewController as a property of an unknown type. But it *is* happy to [send [real messages]] to an unknown type. We also have to (typecast*) to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have tried you solution, but now the console show me the following error "[UINavigationController setDataFromA:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7430850". What's wrong @@?

Comment: you don't sent the message to UINavigationController, you send it to you UIViewController (C)

Comment: Your storyboard Segue is running from A to B. Delete it, and replace it with a segue running from A to C.

Comment: If I add a segue from A to C, where is B? I need a NavigationController because C will push to another ViewController

Comment: C is contained in B. In the storyboard, you 'invoke' B by selecting C, menu > editor > embed in > navigation controller

Comment: if I add a segue from A to C, and select C, "menu > editor > embed in > navigation controller", it will become the same image in question....

Comment: yes but I inferred from your error message, that your segue line was drawn between A and B, not A and C (it is difficult to tell from the picture, you can segue to either but the symbols look slightly different)

Comment: before I use "menu > editor > embed in > navigation controller", the segue line was drawn between A and C, but after "menu > editor > embed in > navigation controller" the segue between A and B like the image in question.... I cann't make the line in A and C....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22691/discussion-between-he-was-and-azure-chen)

Comment: The following is my step: 1.add two ViewController A and C, A have a button. 2.add a segue from the button of A to C. 3.Select C and use "menu > editor > embed in > navigation controller" to add NavigationController. Finally it become the image in question...