# Reference 2nd subview in Modal

Tags: ios, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I have a master/detail app and I'm displaying a modal from my my master view.  My modal contains a navigation controller and two sub views.  The first subview (login) pushes to the second subview (pick and initialize data). How do I get a reference to the second subview so I can catch it's delegate call in my master?

The goal is to update my master table view after the user logs in and initializes the core data database from a JSON webservice.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'subview' I assume you mean the second viewController of your modally-presented navigationController's stack. If so you can't refer forward to it from your master view before you present as it is not yet created (the modal NavController is responsible for that).

You could refer to the *first* viewController - as

```
[[self presentedViewController] topViewController]
```

pass yourself as delegate to that controller, which would then be responsible for passing your delegate reference onwards to the second controller when it is created.

More simply though, you can refer *back* to the presenting setup from your second viewController thus:

```
[[self navigationController] presentingViewController]
```

This will get you to a reference to the container controller from where the presenting took place from where you can easily get a reference to the detail viewController.

You could use that route to get your data back to your master table view.

see also my answer here:
[How can I pass value between NavigationController and ViewController with StoryBoard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307316/how-can-i-pass-value-between-navigationcontroller-and-viewcontroller-with-storyb/14307642#14307642)