# Why isn't my data being passed through view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I am trying to pass textfield text from one controller to another controller so I can email it. I am following an example, but I must be missing some little details. Basically the goal is to pass data textfield text from enteryournamecontroller controller to option controller's nsstring. The nsstring's string variable is being returned null.

EnterYourNameController.h

```
 @interface EnterYourNameController : UIViewController{

  UITextField *textField;

  id <EnterYourNameController> delegate;
 }
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringEntered;
  @property (strong, nonatomic)  UITextField *textField;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;
```

EnterYourNameController.m

```
       -(void)button{
       stringEntered=textField.text;

      ((Options *) (self.delegate)).string = stringEntered;

           UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
Options *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Options"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

       }
```

options.h

```
  @interface Options : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

   NSString *string;
   }
   @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* string;

   @end
```

option.m

```
     NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
```

Comment: Where are you calling Options controller?

Comment: How is this line working?  ((Options *) (self.delegate)).string = stringEntered;

Comment: Im calling the option controller in my button method. I didn't show it because I want to keep it a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Puneet it basically make the string in option equal to stringEntered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `-(void) button` method, initialize the `Options` controller and set the value.

```
-(void)button{

       stringEntered=textField.text;
       Options *optViewController = [[Options alloc] init];
       optViewController.string = stringEntered;
       //call your optViewController here
  }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for some odd reason. I made an NSLog to see if stringEntered was working correctly and it is working.

Comment: Maybe its the way Im moving between controllers.  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    Options *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Options"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: Try using  [self.navigationController pushViewController:optViewController animated:YES]; in the last line of the method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429088/ios-storyboard-passing-data-navigationviewcontroller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307316/how-can-i-pass-value-between-navigationcontroller-and-viewcontroller-with-storyb

Comment: The links may help you.

Comment: Ok, so its been the way I was pushing my controller. I knew I was missing something small.

Comment: Yes. The actual data is been lost when you move between your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, your string in option VC wouldn't live, when you switch between views. So, you must retain string property like this:

```
-(void)button
{
    Options *optViewController = [[Options alloc] init];
    optViewController.string = [[NSString stringWithString:textField.text] retain];
    //call your optViewController here
}
```